# What type should this undeclared variable be?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on some VBA code that another person has written originally. I don't know what objects the variables below are.

```
Set f = fs.GetFile("fullpath")
```

I think that

```
Dim fs As Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

might be correct.

But what is f?

Comment: What does `TypeName (f)` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a File Object.

See the GetFile reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sheydkke(v=vs.84).aspx

And the File Object reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf(v=vs.84).aspx